# Using GPU for NLP data preprocessing

Tags: nlp, data-science

I am trying to preprocess my dataset and I am facing problem like it takes ages to Tokenize and Parts of Speech tagging. I am wondering that can I use GPU for faster processing or I have some issues in my code.
Code I am using for word tokenization is:

```py
def word_tokenizer(text):
    out_result = " "
    for words in text:
        final_result = nltk.tokenize.TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(words)
    return final_result
    
    train_df['review'] = train_df['review'].apply(lambda z: word_tokenizer(z))
```

and my code for parts of speech tagging is:

```py
def pos_tagging(text):
    #data = nltk.pos_tag()
    out_result = " "
    for words in text:
        out_result = nltk.pos_tag_sents(words)
    return out_result
    train_df['review'] = train_df['review'].apply(lambda z: pos_tagging(z))
```

Note: Initially I was using `nltk.pos_tag` but I it was also very slow. I read somewhere that instead of using that use `nltk.pos_tag_sents` but still it is too slow as my dataset is pretty much large.

A help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your tokenizer, you're iterating over the words in your text. Doesn't this mean your text is already tokenized?

Comment: Actually my dataset is movie review dataset in csv format so I have to iterate over every review to tokenize it!

Comment: You're already applying word_tokenizer to each review in your dataset using train_df['review'].apply(). What is the loop in word_tokenizer supposed to do?

Comment: A GPU is not a magical recipe for making things run faster. It's designed for **specific** types of computation: massively parallel floating point math. You're not doing that, so a GPU isn't going to help you.

Comment: @CecilCox thank you for your valuable comment. Fixed my problem by eliminating "for" loop.